# Conversion of date time in jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax

I have a ajax request which get the date time from database. For example, Date time is
 **3/24/2014 10:15:35 AM**, And I want to show this date time into my **razor view page**. 
My Code ::

View code ::

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/CheckLatestTicket",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            var date = Date(data);              
            $("#latestTicket").html("<p style='font-size: 15px;'>" + date + "</p>");
        }
    });
```

Controller Ajax request:

```
    public ActionResult CheckLatestTicket()
    {
        DateTime result = (from t in db.imsticket where t.viewTicketClient == 0 && t.OrganizationId == 1 orderby t.createTicket descending select t.createTicket ).FirstOrDefault();

        return Json(result);
    }
```

Using this code I only get the current date time with the following format::

this is actual result from ajax request

```
   /Date(1395634535793)/
```

This is the result, which is showed in the page: (which is current date time)

```
Mon Mar 24 2014 17:50:26 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time)
```

I want to show this result

```
    3/24/2014 10:15:35 AM
```

Comment: Do you want the date format (dd/mm/yyyy, mm/dd/yyyy) etc to vary based on the browser locale? If not a simple `return Json(result.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"));` will do the formatting server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try client-side conversion so that you can get other information from Ajax request. You can follow the code:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/Home/CheckLatestTicket",
   type: "POST",
   success: function (data) {
      var thisDate = new Date(parseInt(data.substr(6)));    
      $("#latestTicket").html("<p style='font-size: 15px;'>" + thisDate.toLocaleString() + "</p>");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom format the data & time as required like this

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "/Home/CheckLatestTicket",
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        var date = Date(data);       
        var dt= date.customFormat( "#DD#/#MM#/#YYYY# #hh#:#mm#:#ss#" ); //custom formatting       
        $("#latestTicket").html("<p style='font-size: 15px;'>" + dt+ "</p>");
    }
});
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: didnt read that properly, anyway custom formatted the date.

Answer (score 0):

Simply. Send it as a string rather than a DateTime object.

```
public ActionResult CheckLatestTicket()
{
    DateTime result = (from t in db.imsticket where t.viewTicketClient == 0 && t.OrganizationId == 1 orderby t.createTicket descending select t.createTicket ).FirstOrDefault();

    return Json(result.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I was saying in my earlier comment:

Do you want the date format (dd/mm/yyyy, mm/dd/yyyy) etc to vary based on the browser locale? If not a simple `return Json(result.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"));` will do the formatting server-side.

### e.g. Server-side:

```
public ActionResult CheckLatestTicket()
{
    DateTime result = (from t in db.imsticket where t.viewTicketClient == 0 && t.OrganizationId == 1 orderby t.createTicket descending select t.createTicket ).FirstOrDefault();

    return Json(result.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"));
}
```

If you want to do it client side, based on the browser locale, it gets more complicated.

As your data is already a `Date` object a fixed format is easy:

### e.g. Client-side Fixed format:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/CheckLatestTicket",
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        $("#latestTicket").html("<p style='font-size: 15px;'>" + data.customFormat( "#MM#/#DD#/#YYYY# #hh#:#mm#:#ss#" ) + "</p>");
    }
});
```

To dynamically display in the correct locale takes more effort. The `toLocaleDateString()` method of `Date` returns different styles of date *per browser* (full month name vs. month number etc) or you could have done this:

### e.g. Client Side localised format:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/CheckLatestTicket",
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        $("#latestTicket").html("<p style='font-size: 15px;'>" + data.toLocaleDateString() + data.customFormat( " #hh#:#mm#:#ss#" ) + "</p>");
    }
});
```

To go beyond this you could check the locale with `var locale = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;` and test for specific languages, but you have not specified if you need this level of control.